# How to convert date format in HTML using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, date, format

Really new to javascript, so really appreciate your help.

Part of my HTML code contains dates extracted from a form, which they will be printed.

```
<body> 
Test Date<br> 
<span id="test">{{TestDate|"dd/MM/yy"}}</span><br>
Test Date 2<br> 
<span id="test2">{{NextTest|"dd/MM/yy"}}</span><br>
</body>
```

TestDate and NextTest are data obtained from a form and result displayed.  However, the date result is `yyyy-MMM-dd`.

I am trying to have it displayed as `dd/MM/yy`   by using `{{TestDate|"dd/MM/yy"}}`.  However, this doesn't seem to work.

I have seen several options to do this using js, but I am not sure how to use this with HTML, ( tag? and how to make it execute without a trigger / upon load so both dates will be in the correct format prior to printing.)

> Eg var now = new Date();    now.format("dd/MM/yy");    // Returns,
>   e.g., 08/01/18

But not sure how to incorporate/amend this into the above HTML for the date format change to take effect as I don't need a new date, but want to use the dates returned for TestDate and NextTest.

Or do I need to reference to span ID?  if so, how would that work if both dates need converting?

Any help appreciated!

Echo

Comment: There is no built-in *format* property of Date objects, so you must be using a library, framework or something other than plain JS. What is it?

Comment: @RobG thats an angular pipe. He is using angular js i suppose.

Comment: Yes, saw that on w3schools.  But doesn't work, hence the post here...

Comment: @Noob2018 If i get you right, you integrated the angular in your app right ? If so can you edit your question and add angular tag?

Comment: "*…saw that on w3schools*", link? You need to validate anything you find there with some other source.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below to implement the functionality. I have added a class `customDate` to all DOM elements that requires date format conversion and added the code for replacing them in the `onload` function.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var customDates = document.getElementsByClassName('customDate');
  for (var i=0; i<customDates.length; i++) {
    var customDate = new Date(customDates[i].innerHTML);
    var year = customDate.getFullYear();
 var month = (customDate.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    var day = customDate.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    document.getElementsByClassName('customDate')[i].innerHTML = day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
  }
}
```

```html
<body> 
Test Date<br> 
<span class="customDate" id="test">2018-01-08</span><br>
Test Date 2<br> 
<span class="customDate" id="test2">2017-12-10</span><br>
</body>
```

Comment: You're hoping that the built-in parser correctly parses the value of the element's innerHTML (textContent might be better, but not much). Given your output format is d/m/y I'd say it may well fail or be incorrect. Also, where is *padStart* defined?

Comment: @RobG Based on the question, yes, my code assumes that the content of `.customDate` span will always be a date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format and nothing more. Docs for [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Comment: "yyyy-mm-dd" will be parsed as UTC, not local so the result may be off by a day, depending on time and local timezone offset.

Comment: @RobG Thank you for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript you change using `innerHTML` element property. In your case you can do like this.

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=now.format("dd/MM/yy");
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks, but as indicated, I am very new at this, so not sure where this should go.  The var now etc was just an example I found - not sure how Js works, and I don't have any "now" in my html.  Does it just need the line you put above or does it also require a variable declaration?

Comment: put following answer on bottom of body.
`<script>
    function gettoday() {
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd;
        }
        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = '0' + mm;
        }
        var today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
        return today;
    }
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= gettoday();
</script>`

Comment: @Chandraveer—don't add extra information in comments, add it to your answer. If this is just "how to format a Date", then there are many, many duplicates already.

Comment: Okay will look for it. But it seems he does not have idea about how to put javascript to page.

Answer (score 0):

if u have many date format requirements, this lib would help
[moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment)

Comment: Please don't add "use library X" as an answer. It might be a comment, see [*When is “use jQuery” not a valid answer to a JavaScript question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335328/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question), which applies to any similar answer.